# How to use lombok when I build database entity by IDEA automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have installed the plugin:
[image]
and dependency:
[image]

But when I use IDEA to build entity, it will like this:
[image]

I want to replace getter and setter by @Getter,@Setter when IDEA build it automatically.

Comment: can you just remove them?

Comment: why are you worrying about generated code?

Comment: @dehasi of course, but I want to make it automatically. I can do it by myself, but automatic build can save my time

Comment: @Stultuske code can run, I just want to use plugin lombok when idea build it

Comment: my point is ... if it is generated code, your "fix" will be overwritten next build. also Getters will not apply Basic on your getters

Comment: @licxisky Hi, I have the same issue. I have auto generated the entities and their mappings with IntelliJ but now I also want to have lomobok annotations on the entities. Did you figure out a way to do this? Would be a great help to me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just `@Data` Lombok annotation with your entities, for example:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(lenght = 16, nullable = false)
    private String someField;
}
```

In this case you get your entity with automatically created  getters, setters, default constructor (without parameters), `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

Comment: I know how to use lombok, but I want IDEA to use it when it build code use it automatically

Comment: Just use it.. )

Comment: I will build it by myself, Thank you.

Comment: @licxisky did you enable "annotation processor" in IntelliJ after installing the plugin? for working with Lombok in IntelliJ, we need to enable that along with the plugin.

Comment: @ahmadimt I can use Getter, Setter or others, what I want is auto build by idea. I will create the class by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pojo generator plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12297-pojo-generator ,after add @Data annotation